# RavenDB calculate average

Tags: ravendb, average

What's the right way to calculate a simple average with RavenDB?

My object:

```
class Song 
{
    public int CommunityRank { get; set; }
}
```

My first naive thought was, "I'll just use .Sum!", but I got a runtime error saying Raven doesn't do that for performance reasons, which makes sense.

Next thought is, "I'll make a little map/reduce index that calculates it!" So I came up with this:

```
public Songs_CommunityRankIndex()
{
    Map = songs => from song in songs
                   select new 
                   { 
                       Id = song.Id, // # Hack? I only use this for grouping in the reduce.
                       SongCount = 1, 
                       RankSum = song.CommunityRank
                   };

   Reduce = results => from result in results
                       group result by result.Id into g
                       select new
                       {
                           Id = default(string),
                           SongCount = g.Sum(s => s.SongCount),
                           RankSum = g.Sum(s => s.RankSum)
                       };
}


...
// Now to calculate the average:
var communityRankStats = session
                        .Query<Song, Songs_CommunityRankIndex>()
                        .As<Songs_CommunityRankIndex.Results>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                    if (communityRankStats != null)
                    {
                        var averageSongRank = (double)communityRankStats.RankSum / communityRankStats.SongCount;
                    }
```

This works, I think, but feels hackish because there's really nothing to group on, so I just grouped on song ID.

Is there a a better way?

Comment: Judah,
This is utterly broken.
You seem to want to do it on a single document, but because your reduce returns null for the Id, it will all get mixed together.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I didn't understand the implications of having a null Id in the reduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are grouping all items for a single result, then just group by a constant value, such as zero.

Although there's nothing wrong with doing it client side, it is usually convenient to calculate the average inside the index itself.  As long as the sums are being done by map/reduce, then it doesn't really matter if you divide client side or server side.

```
public class Songs_CommunityRankIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Song, Songs_CommunityRankIndex.Results>
{
    public class Results
    {
        public long SongCount { get; set; }
        public long RankSum { get; set; }
        public double RankAverage { get; set; }
    }

    public Songs_CommunityRankIndex()
    {
        Map = songs => from song in songs
                        select new
                            {
                                SongCount = 1,
                                RankSum = song.CommunityRank,
                                RankAverage = 0
                            };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by 0
                            into g
                            let songCount = g.Sum(s => s.SongCount)
                            let rankSum = g.Sum(s => s.RankSum)
                            select new
                                {
                                    SongCount = songCount,
                                    RankSum = rankSum,
                                    RankAverage = rankSum / songCount
                                };
    }
}
```

Comment: Group by zero so that they all get put into a single group. That sounds obvious in retrospect. Thanks!